# Удаление последнего элемента массива

Tags: javascript

не могу понять почему в моем коде удаление происходит только один раз, а при повторном нажатии кнопки удаление не происходит.

```js
var view = {
  value: [],
  displayValue: function(number) {
    var screen = document.getElementById("calc__monitor");
    this.value.push(number);
    screen.innerHTML = this.value.join("");
  }
}

var keyLogger = {
  keys: [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 8],
  parceKey: function(key) {
    key = this.keys.indexOf(key);
    if (key == 10) {
      var lastNum = view.value.length;
      view.value.splice((lastNum - 1), 1);
      console.log(view.value.length);
      view.displayValue();
    } else if (key >= 0) {
      view.displayValue(key);
    }
  }
}

function handleKeyPress(eventObj) {
  var key = eventObj.keyCode;
  console.log(key);
  keyLogger.parceKey(key);
}

function init() {
  var elem = document.querySelector("body");
  elem.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div id="calc__monitor"></div>
```

Comment: Не к месту скажу, но var elem = document.body, там не нужна выборка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в вызове

```
view.displayValue();
```

В этом случае в массив добавляется `undefined` и при следующем удалении удаляется тоже он.

Для решения достаточно проверить, что переданное значение не `undefined`, и добавлять только в этом случае.

Также, вместо [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) для удаления последнего элемента проще использовать [`.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

```js
var view = {
  value: [],
  displayValue: function(number) {
    var screen = document.getElementById("calc__monitor");
    if (number != undefined) {
      this.value.push(number);
    }
    screen.innerHTML = this.value.join("");
  }
}

var keyLogger = {
  keys: [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 8],
  parceKey: function(key) {
    key = this.keys.indexOf(key);
    if (key == 10) {
      view.value.pop();
      console.log(view.value.length);
      view.displayValue();
    } else if (key >= 0) {
      view.displayValue(key);
    }
  }
}

function handleKeyPress(eventObj) {
  var key = eventObj.keyCode;
  console.log(key);
  keyLogger.parceKey(key);
}

function init() {
  var elem = document.querySelector("body");
  elem.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div id="calc__monitor"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, очень помог.